# Orthographic projection in euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a euclidean space with an inner product given by

$$B =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 2 \end{array} \right) $$

in a basis $\{\vec{u_1}, \vec{u_2}, \vec{u_3}\}$. Find the orthographic projection of $\vec{u_3}$ on span$\{\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2}\}.$

**My attempt:** Let $W=\mbox{span}\{\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2}\}$. If $\vec{u_3} \in E$ then there exist $\vec{x} \in W$ and $\vec{y} \in W^{\perp}$ such that $$\vec{u_3} = \vec{x}+\vec{y}.$$ Then $\vec{x} \in W \Rightarrow \vec{x}=\lambda_1\vec{u_1}+\lambda_2\vec{u_2}$ and $\vec{y}=\vec{u_3}-\vec{x} \in W^{\perp} \Rightarrow \vec{y}B\vec{u_1}=\vec{y}B\vec{u_2}=0.$ And i was stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u_3 = w+au_1+bu_2$, where $w$ is orthogonal to $ span\{u_1,u_2\}$.

Take a scalar product with $u_1$ and $u_2$ to  obtain a system on $a$ and $b$:
$$a (u_1,u_1) + b(u_2,u_1)=(u_3,u_1)\\
a (u_1,u_2) + b(u_2,u_2)=(u_3,u_2).$$

Now you need to solve this system, which should be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

Solve $\min_x {1 \over 2} \|Ux-u_3\|_B^2$, where $U= \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Setting the derivative to zero gives
$U^T B^T(Ux-u_3) = 0$, from which we get
$x= (U^TB^T U)^{-1} U^T B^T u_3$